# how to build war which has jars inside it in maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

I have maven project where i have java source code, configuration files and other properties files. i would like build this project to generate a war file where all java source code will go inside rtcc.jar. all configuration files will go into yamldef.jar  and both these jars should go into lib folder of war file. so when i unzip the war file it should have lib folder which contains rtcc.jar and yamldef.jar. Please update how my pom.xml should look like. the java source code is there inside src/main/java folder. configuration files are there inside src/main/resources folder. Please help

Comment: Please explain why want this. What is the advantage of creating these two jars?

Comment: this is the project structure that team is expecting. basically it was an ant project and i am migrating it to maven. the war file structure of ant project was like that. so only i need to build the maven project in same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the classes into a separate jar by using `<archiveClasses>` as decribed here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached

I don't know anything similar for the resources.

Let me say, though: Maven is very different from Ant. It is not sensible to try to rebuild Ant builds in Maven. Instead move forward and accept that structures are different. The team will get used to it and you don't need to bend Maven to behave like Ant.